# Voltages in a circuit with two transformers

Tags: voltage, current, resistors, ac, oscilloscope

Consider the circuit with two transformers in picture.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9Q8yo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I tried to simulate it and I get that on CH1 I see V1 transformed (i.e. V1 times the transformation ratio of T1), while on CH2  I see approximately 0 Volts!

I tried for many values of R and V1 but the results it's always the same, nevertheless when I tried this on a real circuit I saw that both on CH1 and on CH2 I had nonzero sinusoidal voltage (and the difference between voltage was V1 times the transformation ratio).

I do not understand why V on CH2 should be 0 volts at all.., can't current flow in the loop where R is placed? Is this related to the fact that the circuit is open after the second transformer?

Comment: The word you are translating as "tension" should probably actually be "voltage" or "potential". In English, "tension" is only used in a few set phrases from the early days of electrical technology (like "high tension line").

Comment: Are these ideal transformers or do you expect some excitation current in the stored BH curve.

Comment: Put a load on the secondary of T2 to get some current flowing in your circuit. With ideal theoretical transformers there's no current flowing anywhere in your circuit, so no voltage drop across R.

Comment: Don't feel sorry for tension. There really is a tension just like a rubber band and in BE, this was not an uncommon term for it in the past, like high tention line. Germanic laguages, Italian, Spanish and so on uses tension. In AE though, it's voltage due to their love of seeing physical quantities and units as the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a load to the output of T2 while monitoring CH2 and you will then get a reading!

Comment: Care to elaborate? This does somewhat answer the question (and is perhaps better suited as a comment) but could use an explanation as to why current will flow through R2 which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: Sorry about that, this is a lengthy explanation and may be a little clearer with this link and not my wording; https://www.electrical4u.com/theory-of-transformer-on-load-and-no-load-operation/